# Jira - attempting to make a field NOT REQUIRED

Tags: jira

We have an existing text field 'Defect Found Version' (DFV) and a new Field I have created  'Defect Found Version Picker'

I have made the Picker mandatory & that works fine, listing all the cersions on the project.

The DFV field is set to 'Optional' on the right hand side of the Configure Field layout page, however next to the name on the left there is the text REQUIRED & I can not see how to disable this.

Even if I remove this field from all screens I get an error when I create a bug saying that DFV is required.

Any thoughts please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Field Configuration Scheme used by the JIRA project. Then look at the field configuration used for that issue type. That's where it is being made required. Unless it's because of the JIRA Behaviour plugin, so check if that is active

Comment: sorted. Combination of not looking at the correct 'Field Configuration' and not realing the when the text on the right says 'Required' that actually means 'make this field REQUIRED'.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have take a look on your Workflow validator ?
Sometimes, it's required on your workflow, and not on your screen.